# jquery change display mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following html file containing some bunch of div elements each having id and class. I created tabs and page assigned to each tab. The problem is looping through each parent div to set the display of the children div to a different class and make the clicked tab change it's background.

I tried the following :

```
 function MakeActiveTab(CurrentPage, CurrentTab)
  {
    $('#PageID').children().filter(".pageParagraph").css('display','none');
    $('#PageID').children().filter("#" + CurrentPage).css('display', 'block');
    $('#Mainmenu').children().filter(".TabClass").css('background', '#fff');
    $('#Mainmenu').children().filter("#" + CurrentTab).css('background', '#007700;');
  }
```

but it doesn't work!  any idea is appreciated.

```
 <div id='Mainmenu'>
   <div id='menu1' class='TabClass'>
    Tab1
   </div>
   <div id='menu2' class='TabClass'>
    Tab2
   </div>

  </div>

 <div id='PageID'>
       <div id='page1' class='pageParagraph'>
         some content
       </div>

       <div id='page2' class='pageParagraph'>
         some content
       </div>
 </div>
```

I created a javascript function creating pages and menus dynamically into their parent div. That's working fine except I can't get current Tab. When I did that with javascript, it worked but not on IE8.

Comment: "but it doesn't work! " Can you create a fiddle illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="page first-page-name">
    page 1
    <div class="tab first-tab-name">tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab second-tab-name">tab 2</div>
</div>
<div class="page second-page-name">
    page 2
    <div class="tab first-tab-name">tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab second-tab-name">tab 2</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showTabOnPage(tab, page) {
    $('.page').hide().siblings(page).show();
    $('.tab').hide().siblings(tab).show();
}
showTabOnPage('.first-tab-name', '.second-page-name');
```

Check out the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/3WtyF

If the structure of your page is not the same - sorry. But I hope the general idea will be clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

found a way arround it. Thanks.

```
   refID = document.getElementById('Mainmenu').childNodes;
            for (i = 0; i < refID.length; i++)
            {
                if (refID[i].id == 'TabClass' + objID)
                {
                    MakeActiveTab("TabClass" + objID, "pageParag" + objID);

                    return 0;
                }
            }
```

That's the majic!